# Use other pandas column to dictate regular expression in Series.contains

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe with a long text field and a short string that is essentially a category.  My goal is utilize a regular expression to create a new column in the dataframe corresponding to whether there is a match.  The regular expression is conditioned upon on the category.  Here's an example:

```
a = ['the dog is mad and sad 50', 'the cat is happy']
b = ['dog', 'cat']
regex = ['[0-9]{2}', '[0-9]{3}']

ab = pd.DataFrame(zip(a,b,regex), columns = ['text', 'category', 'pattern'])
```

In the example above, to avoid using a for loop to loop through each category, I've made the pattern a string column in my dataframe and want to use the pattern column as the regular expression.

However when I run the following I'm getting an error

```
ab['match'] = np.where(ab[ab['text'].str.contains(ab['pattern'], regex = True)], 1, 0)

TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

The dataframe is very large and there are potentially many categories, so a vectorized solution like above would be preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to apply a specific regular expression to a specific row, you can't use a [vectorized approach](https://www.xkcd.com/1691/). You'll have to use a row-wise apply:

```py
import re

ab['match'] = ab.apply(lambda row: bool(re.search(row['pattern'], row['text'])), axis=1)

                        text category   pattern  match
0  the dog is mad and sad 50      dog  [0-9]{2}   True
1           the cat is happy      cat  [0-9]{3}  False
```

Comment: The `np.where` is redundant.

Comment: Lol, love the xkcd.